# Create std::array from variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'd like to achieve something like that:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>

enum class MyEnum{
  A,
  B,
  C
};

template<MyEnum... Args>   
class MyClass{
  public:
    MyClass()
    {
    }
  private:
    std::array<MyEnum, sizeof...(Args)> array;   
};
```

Now I have an array, which can hold all passed to template values. But how can I populate this array with template parameters?

Comment: You can't use strings as template arguments.

Comment: Good point! I will correct the example.

Comment: @MiniKarol please look at my updated answer. The accepted answer is not as efficient or pretty as the updated one (thanks to Xeo).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you are wanting is to put all the `MyEnum` values into `array`, then you can <strike>unpack them into an initialiser list and initialise `array` with it</strike> **initialise it with direct initialisation**:

```
MyClass() : array {{ Args... }} { }
```

You need a fairly new compiler to use this syntax, however.

Thanks to Xeo for correcting my answer.

Comment: This won't work as `std::array` does not have a constructor that accepts an `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @n.m. oh, that seems weird. Why does `array<int, 4> a { 1, 2, 3, 4 };` work then?

Comment: @Seth: Direct initialization, `std::array` is a POD type. You can use that same syntax in the member initializer btw.

Comment: @Xeo oh that explains it then, I didn't know `array` was POD. Thanks. What do you mean "you can use that same syntax in the member initializer"?

Comment: `MyClass() : array{1, 2, 3, 4}`

Comment: @Xeo [is it just that this version of GCC is too old for that?](http://ideone.com/Wo2YY)

Comment: @Seth: I think so, can't try Clang ToT or GCC 4.7 right now. Maybe ask in the C++ chat room?

Comment: Thank it works perfectly but I have to enclose Args... within two pairs of brackets - MyClass(): array{{Args...}}{}

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass()
{
    std::initializer_list<MyEnum> il( {Args...} );
    std::copy (il.begin(), il.end(), array.begin());
}
```