# matrix class , variadic constructor

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to create a simple matrix class, the point is that i'm using standard pointer to store the data .. and I don't know 2 things 
how can i solve the problem of this constructor :

```
template<typename data_type>
template <typename ... Ts>   
constexpr Matrix<data_type>::Matrix(std::size_t row , 
                                    std::size_t col ,
                                    Ts&&... args     ) noexcept : row{row}, columns{col},
                                                                   data{ new data_type[row*col] },

{
        std::size_t i =0;    
        assert(sizeof...(args) == row*columns );    
        data[i++] = (std::forward<Ts>(args)...);          
}
```

i got the error :

```
In file included from matrixDrive.cpp:3:0:
matrix.H: In constructor ‘constexpr Matrix<U>::Matrix(std::size_t, std::size_t, Ts&& ...)’:
matrix.H:93:1: error: expected identifier before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
matrix.H: In instantiation of ‘constexpr Matrix<U>::Matrix(std::size_t, std::size_t, Ts&& ...) [with Ts = {double, double, double, double, double, double}; data_type = double; std::size_t = long unsigned int]’:
matrixDrive.cpp:11:68:   required from here
matrix.H:96:19: error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘double’ in assignment
         data[i++] = {std::forward<Ts>(args)...};
         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
matrixDrive.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
matrixDrive.cpp:13:3: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘return’
   return 0;
   ^~~~~~
```

here the whole implementation:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <utility>
# include <iomanip>
# include <vector>
# include <exception>
# include <iterator>
# include <cassert>

template <class U> class Matrix ;

template <class U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& , Matrix<U>& );

template <class U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ,const Matrix<U>& ); 


//- class declararation
//
template <typename data_type = double>
class Matrix {

   public:   
    //- friend function
    template <class U>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ,Matrix<U>& ); 

    template <class U>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ,const Matrix<U>& ); 





   public:
    constexpr Matrix(std::size_t r = 3 , std::size_t c = 3) noexcept;  

    constexpr Matrix(std::size_t r, std::size_t c, data_type val) noexcept;  

    template <typename ... Ts>   
    constexpr Matrix(std::size_t row , std::size_t col, Ts&&... args) noexcept;  

    virtual ~Matrix() noexcept ; 


    auto constexpr zeros() noexcept ;

    auto constexpr initialize(data_type) noexcept ;

    data_type& operator()(std::size_t, std::size_t);  

//-------
   private:   

      data_type *data     ;
      std::size_t row     ;
      std::size_t columns ;

      auto constexpr isAllocate() noexcept { return data != nullptr ; } 

};

// Matrix definition

//- standard constructor
template<typename data_type>
constexpr Matrix<data_type>::Matrix(std::size_t r, std::size_t c) noexcept : row{r}, columns{c}, 
                                                                     data{new data_type[r*c]}
{
      this->zeros();
}


template<typename data_type>
constexpr Matrix<data_type>::Matrix(std::size_t r, std::size_t c, data_type val) noexcept : row{r}, columns{c}, 
                                                                                            data{new data_type[r*c]}
{
      this->initialize(val);
}  


//--- construct by list of arguments
template<typename data_type>
template <typename ... Ts>   
constexpr Matrix<data_type>::Matrix(std::size_t row , 
                                    std::size_t col ,
                                    Ts&&... args     ) noexcept : row{row}, columns{col},
                                                                   data{ new data_type[row*col] },

{
        std::size_t i =0;    
        assert(sizeof...(args) == row*columns );    
        data[i++] = (std::forward<Ts>(args)...);          
}


// destructor
template<typename data_type>
Matrix<data_type>::~Matrix() noexcept 
{
      if( isAllocate() )
            delete[] data; 
}





//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//

template <typename data_type>
auto constexpr Matrix<data_type>::zeros() noexcept {
   if(isAllocate())
     for(size_t i=0; i< row*columns ; i++)
            data[i] = 0; 
}


template <typename data_type>
auto constexpr Matrix<data_type>::initialize(data_type val) noexcept
{
      if(isAllocate())
         for(size_t i=0 ; i < row*columns; i++)
            data[i] = val ;
}




//-----------

template <typename data_type>
data_type& Matrix<data_type>::operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) { return data[(i-1) + row* (j-1)] ; }  


// non member function 

template <class U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out ,Matrix<U>& mat)
{
    for(std::size_t r = 1; r < mat.row+1 ; r++)
    {
      for(std::size_t c = 1; c < mat.columns+1 ; c++)
      {
          out << mat(r,c) << ' ' ;  
      }
      out << "\n" ;
    }
}

template <class U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out , const Matrix<U>& mat) 
{
    for(std::size_t r = 1; r < mat.row+1 ; r++)
    {
      for(std::size_t c = 1; c < mat.columns+1 ; c++)
      {
          out << mat(r,c) << ' ';  
      }
      out << "\n" ;
    }
}
```

and the main function :

```
# include <iostream>
# include <iomanip>
# include "matrix.H"

using namespace std;

int main() {

  Matrix<double> m1, m2(6,3);    

  Matrix<double> m3(3,2,1.12,2.434,3.546546,4.657,5.675675,6.542354)    

  return 0;    
}
```

thanks in advance for your precious help!

Comment: Note that your code snippet does not match the error. In the code you have round braces around the `std::forward` call, in the error it's curly ones. Did you forget `data_type` in front of `std::forward`?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: oh yes I've tried with both round and curly brackets

Comment: Please post the error you get for the code you've put in your post. It makes no sense to show an error for code we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying to [parameter pack expansion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) doesn't work. It will expand the whole list of arguments and try and assign them to `data[1]`.

The answer from [Create std::array from variadic template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364874/create-stdarray-from-variadic-template) works here as well:

```
template<typename data_type>
template <typename ... Ts>
constexpr Matrix<data_type>::Matrix(std::size_t row ,
                                    std::size_t col ,
                                    Ts&&... args     ) noexcept : row{row}, columns{col},
                                                                   data{ new data_type[row*col] }

{
        std::size_t i =0;
        assert(sizeof...(args) == row*columns );

        std::initializer_list<data_type> il ( { std::forward<Ts>(args)... } );
        std::copy(il.begin(), il.end(), data);
}
```

Note that the code you posted has a bunch of bugs. It doesn't even compile, since there's a semi-colon missing in the main function. There's also a bunch of warnings you get if you compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pendantic`.

Comment: I see ... ?  how can I repair ?

Comment: @MarcoGhiani Repair what? The errors? The compiler tells you what is wrong and most of the time how to solve it (most errors seemed to be e.g. functions not returning something).